# Dart serializing immutable objects

Tags: serialization, dart

I would like serialize this immutable class

```
class CatalogueItem {
  final Uri source;
  final DateTime analyis;
  final Period fromTo;

  CatalogueItem.create(this.source, this.analyis, this.fromTo);
}
```

But I cannot as it is not a simple class. From the web site https://www.dartlang.org/articles/serialization/

> Simple: All of the objects to be serialized are data transfer objects
>   (DTOs) with a default constructor.

So I have to add a default constructor - which means I have to drop the final keywords and my class is no longer immutable.

```
class CatalogueItem {
  Uri source;
  DateTime analyis;
  Period fromTo;

  CatalogueItem.create(this.source, this.analyis, this.fromTo);
  CatalogueItem(){}
}
```

Is there any way around this one?

Comment: Try the dartson package, that offers some customization options. If you run into a bug or issue, please update this question with the code that you tried and any errors you might be getting. Thanks!

Comment: I think the default constructor is only necessary for deserialization (never used a package for (de)serialization). Serialization shouldn't need it.

Comment: The api complains if you don't have a public default constructor when you serialize an object. I also need to deserialize it

Answer (score 1):

I think the default constructor is only necessary for deserialization (never used a package for (de)serialization). Serialization shouldn't need it.

The default constructor is redundant because if the deserialization package needs a default constructor it obviously attempts to create an instance using the default constructor to afterwards set the field values, which can't work with final fields.

I don't know if a serialization package supports a custom `toJson()` method/`fromJson()` constructor but I think this would be the easiest way to go.

```
class CatalogueItem {
  final Uri source;
  final DateTime analysis;
  final Period fromTo;

  CatalogueItem.create(this.source, this.analysis, this.fromTo);
  factory CatalogueItem.fromJson(Map json) {
    return new CatalogueItem.create(
        json['source']   == null ? null : Uri.parse(json['source']),
        json['analysis'] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json['analysis'])),
        json['fromTo']   == null ? null : new Period.fromJson(json['fromTo']));
  }

  Map toJson() {
    return {
      'source':   source == null ? null : '$source', 
      'analysis': analysis == null ? null : '$analysis', 
      'fromTo':   fromTo == null ? null : fromTo.toJson();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/google/built_value.dart may do what you want -- it is specifically for creating immutable classes and serializing them.

Note that this requires a slightly different form for the class. This is to allow built_value to generate an implementation for you, and serializers.

```
abstract class CatalogueItem
    implements Built<CatalogueItem, CatalogueItemBuilder> {
  static Serializer<CatalogueItem> get serializer
      => _$catalogueItemSerializer;

  Uri get source;
  DateTime get analyis;
  Period get fromTo;

  factory CatalogueItem([updates(CatalogueItemBuilder b)]) =
      _$CatalogueItem;
  CatalogueItem._();
}
```

The generated implementation is immutable (uses final), and also provides operator==, hashCode and toString.

More detailed example: https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/example/lib/example.dart

Answer (score 0):

One option is to read further in the article and use the serialization package, which does handle such cases.